# Add letter to a list (Polymorphic func)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am beginner in Haskell, I have an exercise in which the idea is to make polymorphic functions.

I want to make a function which takes list and another argument to be added to that list.

```
addA :: a -> [a] -> [a]
addA [] = []
addA (x: xs) = x + a : addA xs
```

in the last line there is an error showing: saying that variable a is not in scope and ->

```
Couldn't match expected type: [a1]
              with actual type: [[a1]] -> [[a1]]
• Probable cause: ‘addA’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘addA xs’
  In the expression: x + a : addA xs
  In an equation for ‘addA’: addA (x : xs) = x + a : addA xs
• Relevant bindings include
    xs :: [a1]
```

I don't know how to add the input in every element in the list.

Comment: Is this the *exact* code you have? I would not expect that error from this code; rather, I would expect a complaint that `a` is not in scope.

Comment: Yes, I have exactly the same code.

Answer (score 3):

When you're using plain Haskell without any advanced language extensions, the compiler is able to infer the type of functions from expressions. Therefore, the type annotation is really optional.

Consider, then, the function definition *without* type annotation:

```
addA [] = []
addA (x: xs) = x + a : addA xs
```

In this case, the compiler error is *still*

```
error: Variable not in scope: a
```

Can you see why that is now?

Comment: In the exercise one of the requirements is that the the function has to have the definition. In the error of variable `a`, the thing is that I want to use the first parameter to be added to every element in the list but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @diegog You can write the function first, and once you've figured out how to implement the desired function, you can add the type annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what the signature of `addA` has:

```hs
addA :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

This means in order to call `addA`, you need to provide *two* arguments.

However, in your definition:

```hs
addA [] = [] -- There is only one parameter specified on the left side of '=', i.e. []
addA (x: xs) = x + a : addA xs -- There is only one parameter specified on the left side of '=', i.e. (x:xs)
```

That is what the compiler is complaining about.

If you are unsure how to correctly implement the algorithm but want to get past the type checking, you can use a discard pattern (the `_`):

```hs
addA _ [] = []
addA _ (x: xs) = x + a : addA xs -- This still would not compile, but is caused by the fact that 'a' is not in scope in your implementation
```

---

With that said, since the question is asking for a polymorphic implementation, the most polymorphic implementation I can come up with is this:

```hs
addA :: (Functor f, Num a) => a -> f a -> f a
addA = fmap . (+)
```

This is polymorphic in the sense that it works on any numeric type `a` (`Int`, `Double`, etc.) and any functorial type `f` (`[]`, `Maybe`, `Either`, etc.) so that:

```hs
addA 2 [1, 2] -- returns [3, 4]
addA 3.0 (Just 3.0) -- returns Just 6.0
addA 7 (2, 5) -- returns (2, 12)
```

Comment: thank you. Do you have any idea about the erros in the last line saying that the variable a is not in scope and the one with addA xs.

Comment: Variable `a` is not in scope means `a` was not defined previously—either in the definition of the function itself, globally within the current module, or imported from any modules.

Comment: I mean, I want the first argument to be added to every element of the list, thats why I am using x + a

Comment: Then you will need a name for the first argument in order for the implementation to refer to it: `addA a (x:xs) = x + a : addA a xs`